# Can I deploy wars with different jar versions to Jetty?

Tags: java, servlets, jar, jetty, war

I have several webapps but some of them have different versions of the same jars. Can these be deployed to the same Jetty instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; this is the reason for recommending packaging dependencies in `WEB-INF/lib` instead of putting them in the container's classpath. Each Web application in a container gets its own class loader and has distinct runtime instances of the classes it uses.